# The difference between directly binding and using each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each

I am really confused about each function.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ComboZhc/5Dy7D/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //$(".a").click(function(){
            //  alert("hi");
            //});
            $(".a").each(function(){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    alert("hi");
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="a">hi</div>
    <div class="a">hi</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's the difference between using `.click` function directly and using `.each`? Both of them works.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

If these two methods are the same, could you please give an example why `.each` is necessary?

Comment: There's no difference (in this case).  Sometimes it's necessary to use `.each()`, but not in your example.

Comment: @Pointy could you give an example?

Comment: In this case, the .each is extra work since selector already iterates through it, but the result as others have already stated results in the same thing.

Comment: @ComboZhc an example of when it's necessary to use `.each()` would be a situation in which the nature of the event handler might be different for each matched element, based on some other element attributes or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is a difference here. With `.each` you create a new function in every iteration and each element gets a different function object assigned as event handler.
 This is not the case if you call `.click` on the whole selection. It will use the function you pass to it as event handler for each element. The behaviour in the end is the same though.

You could avoid creating a new function object by creating it once before you iterate over the elements:

```
var handler = function(){
    alert("hi");
};
$(".a").each(function(){
    $(this).click(handler);
});
```

But it is unnecessary to do so. `.click` calls `.on` internally which in turn will call `.each` to iterate over the selected elements and bind the event handler.

`.each` is just a generic way to iterate over the elements and do whatever you want with them. For example, you might want to replace a word inside each element by another word:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace('foo', 'bar'));
});
```

This is not a very good example because also here there is a neater way to do it, but I hope it gives you some idea.

---

**Why is there a performance difference between these two ways?**

The outer `.each` call is redundant and adds an additional overhead. The "call chain" will look similar to this:

```
each (1 time)
  -> callback (N times)
    -> click (1 time) (N times in total)
      -> on (1 time) (N times in total)
        -> each (1 time) (N times in total)
          -> callback (which ultimately adds the event handler) (1 time) (N times in total)
```

In comparison, this is roughly what happens when you call `.click` directly:

```
click (1 time)
  -> on (1 time)
    -> each (1 time)
      -> callback (which ultimately adds the event handler) (N times)
```

So not only are more functions executed, but additional, the same functions (like `.click` nad `.on`) are executed multiple times. Each function might make checks or initialise variables *once* per call, so obviously if you call it multiple times, it will take more time.

Comment: And what does the internal `.each` do if not create a new event handler in every iteration?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how `.each` create new event handler and `.click` or `.on` does not?

Comment: @Radu well the point is that there's just one `function` object instantiated, instead of a function for each element.

Comment: @Pointy but internally `.click` just call `.each` with the `function` instantiated?

Comment: @ComboZhc right - a single function object is instantiated and passed to the `.click()` function, and it'll be used for all the elements. The behavior of the page would be the same, other than the instantiation of a lot of extra functions.

Comment: [jspert test](http://jsperf.com/click-vs-each-click/3), I have revisioned François Wahl's test but I've got the result that `.each` is still 18% lower than `.click` even instantiating the `function` only once. Could you give more explanation?

Comment: @ComboZhc: Do you get the same result when you remove the alerts? I'm not 100% sure but I think jsPerf having to supress the alerts might have an impact on execution.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Using `.each` is always slower. I have tested with and without alert. I also switch the sequence of those two tests.

Answer (score 2):

`.click` on a list of elements `($('selector').length > 1)` is internally looped thru by jQuery to add the events.

`.each` and `.click` is done just by you.. but then it goes thru the same jQuery iterate code.

I prefer using the 1st as it is neater in your end.

Comment: +1. In addition, not only is it neater but also executes about >25% faster than using each in this case: http://jsperf.com/click-vs-each-click (I know it is milliseconds but eitherway a bonus in performance)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference and it amounts to the same thing if you follow the jquery source. I would therefore recommend using simply `click`.